# Making a Like/Dislike AJAX script - Not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, sql-like

I'm just building the like side of it first. Basically, I just want it to automatically run an external PHP/MySQL script that adds a +1 to the "rating" column for what was liked. I want this to happen without reloading the page, hence AJAX. I've never used AJAX and I'm having some trouble getting it to work. Below is the relevant code and I put a link to where I'm working on it at at the bottom of this post.

Here's the form to start:

```
<div id="voting">    
<form>   
  <input name="vote" type='button' onclick="getVote(<?php echo $image['filename'];?>)" value='Like' /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the AJAX part of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getVote(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("voting").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php"+filename,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And finally, the voting.php script that's supposed to run:

```
<?php
//Database Information
$dbhost = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";

//Connect to database
mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$filename = $_GET['filename'];

$query = "UPDATE images SET rating = rating+1 WHERE filename = '$filename'";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

?>
```

[Here](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons)'s the site it's supposed to go on if it's of any help to anyone. I'd really appreciate any kind of help. Absolutely clueless and I've never used AJAX before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens/do not happen? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want it to run that external PHP script like you would with a regular form, but without reloading the page, hence AJAX. I'm just having trouble getting it to work. You can see what's going wrong on the site, I left the link at the bottom.

Comment: What the hell? For some reason the site I gave is having a weird problem... Everything is marqueeing across the left nav...

Comment: Start by narrowing it down a bit. Insert some alerts and echos here and there to know what code get's executed and what does not.

Comment: I know what the problem is I think. I'm finding the `filename` between the parenthesis of the AJAX function, but I don't think I'm including it correctly with the `xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php"+filename,true);`.

On a side note, does anyone have an idea of why my site is doing this weird scrolling thing all of the sudden? I don't think I did anything that would have caused that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem, but you aren't sending any parameter to the voting url.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","voting.php?filename="+filename,true);
```

Also, you would like to protect that script for simple forms of sql injection.

```
$filename = isset($_GET['filename']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['filename']) : null ;

if (is_null($filename)) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This begs the question, that since user996494 is using jqueryui, why not use jquery to handle the ajax calls too.

Comment: @gview: I agree. That would be the easiest way to get this working.

Comment: gview, oso, how do you guys suggest I do that?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! (to original answerer) Now I just need to figure out this response text thing...

Comment: Would you have any idea how to return the updated points when it finishes adding your like?

Comment: @user996494: yes, since you're already using jquery for other things, I think it will be cleaner and more reliable for you to stay with it for the ajax. I think you will agree that the api is very easy:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. Also to answer your followup: do a query after the update to SELECT the rating and echo that result out. jQuery makes it simple to handle this result with a callback function you provide, however, it appears your function handles a result as well.

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I'm probably going to keep it in AJAX though. It works, and I'm quite happy when that happens :P Thanks for all the help